# Update GnuTLS for JHBuild

Tags: compiling, gtk, gtk3, gnutls

I am trying to compile `GTK+` from source and have installed `JHBuild` for this purpose. I've already managed to build `PyGObject` using `JHBuild` and the `sanitycheck` runs without output.

For building `GTK+` it seems that `JHBuild` needs `GnuTLS` >= version 3.0 as it states in the terminal:

```
checking for GNUTLS... no
configure: error: in `/home/xiaolong/jhbuild/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.90/glib-networking-2.45.1':
configure: error: "Requested 'gnutls >= 3.0' but version of GnuTLS is 2.12.23
You may find new versions of GnuTLS at http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/"
See `config.log' for more details
*** Error during phase configure of glib-networking: ########## Error running ./configure --prefix /home/xiaolong/jhbuild/releases/gnome-apps-3.17.90/install --enable-installed-tests --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc --disable-Werror  *** [13/29]
```

So I searched and found the following instructions on how to build `GnuTLS` in a more recent version than installed on my system:

http://www.bauer-power.net/2014/06/how-to-install-gnutls-3123-from-source.html

I needed to install some libraries to complete the instructions without errors, but that's done. Now I thought `JHBuild` would surely run fine until the next error in the build process of `GTK+`, but that wasn't the case. Instead I still see the same error message about requiring a version >= 3.0 of `GnuTLS`. It seems `JHBuild` has a problem locating the `GnuTLS` build from source and still finds the one installed from the package management system instead.

How do I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to uninstall the library `libgnutls28`, which was previously installed using `apt`. After that I ran the jhbuild build command again and got other errors, not related to GnuTLS anymore, so I guess they don't fit into this question.